# Cant open video with videoCapture opencv

Tags: python, opencv, video, video-streaming

I have following code which reads frames from video file and stores as jpg. The code works fine if I read frames from camera directly but for video file it doesn't read the frames.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('C:/Users/lostpanda.mp4')
#cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
count = 0
while cap.isOpened():
  ret,frame = cap.read()
  print(ret,frame)
  cv2.imshow('window-name', frame)
  name = 'C:/Users/video_testing/video-frames/' + str(count) + '.jpg'
  #cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, frame)
  cv2.imwrite(name,frame)
  count = count + 1
  if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
```

Thanks

Comment: hey ! What is the error message?

Comment: Thanks@VidyaGanesh, I don't get any error while I run the above code,but I am unable to read frames and save them in a folder. The code works fine if I change the input to read frames from video

Comment: consider using ffmpeg standalone. it can unpack videos into a series of pictures. your problem description should say "can't open video with VideoCapture", the rest is not part of the problem.

Comment: windows... UAC issue>? try turn it to low?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this instead:

```
import cv2 
import os 

# Read the video from specified path 
cam =cv2.VideoCapture(r"C:/Users/lostpanda.mp4") 

try:
    # creating a folder named data 
    if not os.path.exists('video-frames'): 
        os.makedirs('video-frames') 

# if not created then raise error 
except OSError: 
    print ('Error: Creating directory of data') 

# frame 
currentframe = 0

while(True): 
  
# reading from frame 
    ret,frame = cam.read() 

    if ret: 
        # if video remains continue creating images 
        name = './video-frames/frame' + str(currentframe)+ '.jpg'
        print ('Creating...' + name) 

        # write extracted images 
        cv2.imwrite(name, frame) 

        #Counter to show number of frames that are being created 
        currentframe += 1
    else: 
        break

# Release all space and windows once done 
cam.release() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Hi, @VidyaGanesh, I tried this but I noticed in my previous code and this code too I am unable to read frames when I print frame, I retrieve none. and my file path is correct